# Assigning a background image to another in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the background image of a div so that it's the same as another div's background. I can get the "onload success" alert, but I can't get the thumbBG background to change. All solutions show assigning it to a URL but I would like to assign it to another divs background instead.

```
var thumbBG=document.getElementById("videos-bg");
var initialThumb=document.getElementById("v-thumb1");
var test = function(){
    alert("onload success")
    thumbBG.style.backgroundImage = initialThumb.style.backgroundImage;
};
window.onload=test();
```

Thanks.

Comment: use `window.onload=test` instead - because `window.onload` needs to be a function, not the result of calling a function

Comment: well is here an error message in the console?

Comment: @epascarello I get an XML parsing error and "Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js”." although from a quick search that seems to be because I have adblock enabled.

Comment: @JaromandaX If I leave out the parentheses, the function doesn't run on window load.

Comment: really? it should - if you have the parenthesis it runs immediately, not on load - perhaps your window.onload event has already fired by the time this code is parsed - how is it laoded? inline? externl async? external defer?

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm confused, is there a difference between run on load and immediately run? I'm new to HTML, I don't know what those terms mean i'm afraid.

Comment: Means you are calling the function and assigning what it returns to the event handler. It is NOT saying, run this function onload.

Comment: @JaromandaX Okay. I did manage to get the script to run although the main problem is that I can't assign and display an image for a divs background based on another div's bg.

Answer (score 0):

First look the **DEMO** here: https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/JpLYNb

Here is your js code:

```
var thumbBG=document.getElementById("videos-bg");
var initialThumb=document.getElementById("v-thumb1");
style = initialThumb.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(initialThumb, false),
    bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1);
var test = function(){
    thumbBG.style.backgroundImage = 'bi';
  thumbBG.style.backgroundImage = "url("+ bi +")";
};
window.onload=test();
```

**If you need explanation please let me know...**